# Why XmlSchemaSet explicitely sets targetNamespace to chameleon schemas

Tags: .net, xsd, system.xml, xmlschemaset

For example, I have 2 Xml schemas:

a.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="test" targetNamespace="test">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="b.xsd" />
</xsd:schema>`
```

b.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="testType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="test"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="test" type="testType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Second schema does not have *targetNamespace* and used as a chameleon schema.

I am trying to pre-load these schemas using XmlSchemaSet:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add(null, @"a.xsd");

foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())  // foreach is used to simplify the example
{
    Console.WriteLine("Target namespace: "schema.TargetNamespace);  // "Target namespace: test"
    XmlSchemaInclude include = (XmlSchemaInclude)schema.Includes[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Include target namespace: " + include.Schema.TargetNamespace); // "Include target namespace: test"
}
```

But after I do it both schemas have "test" target namespace. I expect instantiated schema objects should be equal to source schemas, but it is not true for schema "b.xsd". 
Why it behaves so and is there any way to disable such a behavior?

Answer (score 2):

When you include b.xsd from a.xsd, you are effectively saying that you want b.xsd to have the same target namespace as a.xsd.  The term *chameleon include* denotes the process of making that happen, given a schema document which (like b.xsd) has no specification of a target namespace.

If you want the `test` element and the `testType` type declared in b.xsd not to be in namespace `test`, then you do not want to use b.xsd as a chameleon, and you should not include b.xsd from a.xsd.  You may wish to use xs:import instead.

But perhaps I don't understand what you are after.